# Why am I receiving (apparently) random results from my MySQL query?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

For clarification, I am essentially re-writing this question.

I have a table, as defined below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('banned','moderated','user','author','moderator','admin','owner') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
  `password` char(128) NOT NULL,
  `salt` char(128) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

The table dump -- with e-mail field redacted -- is:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `user`
--

INSERT INTO `user` (`userid`, `name`, `email`, `status`, `password`, `salt`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'Rilbur Skryler', '', 'owner', '2008dff1d727007691867904af3a96677ec81847ff943470a9596b184ffdb8b0de03e6fa68d9a6cb03170bff78d8d50f703bcec9120727b9eee5dbceeb1bc26e', '5647f4d6165a42a17d1ac6a46f13dc11d4a3d8d4fcd7b16f88f0fecc659bd1a9ddd1cb79002a8b1ab9daf4da549dd2e516806cc4603dd20cbdde175bd5961049', 'Site owner and administrator'),
(2, 'Zacky', '', 'author', 'e7a10ef6b58734093286bb7ebba65b8dd36c1cc18bc59f16a6e05760230f228fbb0464131b6c1e4768e26792e9194f43d78c277eb7ac86775f9b46bbe4d9dde2', 'f42029a7c657e3998443ca1f1043202f8431fba3ec9471e389752e3e83c790d6193292678a5878dd45ba6d7496521bf8ecd6e469455d4c34d95b36495691941a', 'Wacky!'),
(3, 'Roland', '', 'author', 'e7a10ef6b58734093286bb7ebba65b8dd36c1cc18bc59f16a6e05760230f228fbb0464131b6c1e4768e26792e9194f43d78c277eb7ac86775f9b46bbe4d9dde2', 'f42029a7c657e3998443ca1f1043202f8431fba3ec9471e389752e3e83c790d6193292678a5878dd45ba6d7496521bf8ecd6e469455d4c34d95b36495691941a', 'Involuntary addition.');
```

The actual PHP code (with added comments) is:

```
$query="select ".db_prefix."user.salt, ".db_prefix."user.password from ".db_prefix."user where ".db_prefix."user.userid=:id";
echo $query.$id;//generates: select user.salt, user.password from user where user.userid=:id
$statement=$db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(array('id'=>$id));
if($row=$statement->fetch())
{
    $salt=$row[0];//row[0] is filled with a randomized result as shown two lines down
    var_dump($row);
    echo "pre one: $salt\r\n";//I'm outputting the value of the salt, which appears to be randomly generated.
    echo "one";
    $passwordsalt=generateValueFromPasswordAndSalt($password, $salt);//Used to call the routine that generates a value from the combination of a password string and the salt.
    return $passwordsalt==$row[1];//This always returns 'false' because the stored password value never matches the generated value, as a result of the salt being the wrong string.
}
```

This problem has been driving me batty.  The value retrieved for the salt appears to be randomly generated (I say 'appears' because I know it shouldn't be random, I have to be missing something).  Various changes, such as reversing the salt and password values in the query or replacing them with a select * resolve the problem.  That's great, but I don't understand *why* they solve it, so I don't trust them.  (Plus, I want to learn why it's happening so I can avoid it in the future)

If it matters, I'm using a PDO database object initialized as follows:

```
function get_DB()
{
    static $db;
    if(isset ($db))
    {
        return $db;
    }
    else
    {
        try{
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".db_host.";dbname=".db_name;
        $db = new PDO($dsn, updater_login, updater_password);
        return $db;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            //echo $e->getMessage();
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Randomly returned salt values include:

9ed1358ccb614ee86f17a3cc964caaad3ab8ede7d705960aac2d5f4448c0f85d0acf581e2225d567789ac2f678b6a6662e4e7a8e55efb0d92be903249c44af7f

6feff9b576ba0b0aa5e3d61996e723ddc4bdc3e7777469409b4da095aae6fb9a6df84fdaa96029a27e07714c670d18c2b8707453e515a3632383b6b03925b04b

60fdc33fa77029f4627c39558417b1bb492a02d8cd56571b3091aff2123ee5545c5717a6a7c0553c7c659864e947f28c65627f3d288c51ef6c9b6de3f5175417

PHP output:

Run One:

```
select user.salt, user.password from user where user.userid=:id1<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b>
  'salt' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'15316153f3206618917cf7319747eda5871a7b8e942b54dba6f42e8bc491197450285504a37eb825e6aff04871fde52c49e029cf7e3a1d8cb9fe8a0422f4cd03'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'15316153f3206618917cf7319747eda5871a7b8e942b54dba6f42e8bc491197450285504a37eb825e6aff04871fde52c49e029cf7e3a1d8cb9fe8a0422f4cd03'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
  'password' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'a0d2c6b1bf7163f85738627ffbfd5bd343e9bdaf0b98f00f63f020abac398df426d01f1bdcd8a46771af881640a4210b536cc89b7cea91637d7db705e64144cc'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'a0d2c6b1bf7163f85738627ffbfd5bd343e9bdaf0b98f00f63f020abac398df426d01f1bdcd8a46771af881640a4210b536cc89b7cea91637d7db705e64144cc'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
</pre>pre one: 15316153f3206618917cf7319747eda5871a7b8e942b54dba6f42e8bc491197450285504a37eb825e6aff04871fde52c49e029cf7e3a1d8cb9fe8a0422f4cd03

one
```

Run Two:

```
select user.salt, user.password from user where user.userid=:id1<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b>
  'salt' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'5647f4d6165a42a17d1ac6a46f13dc11d4a3d8d4fcd7b16f88f0fecc659bd1a9ddd1cb79002a8b1ab9daf4da549dd2e516806cc4603dd20cbdde175bd5961049'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'5647f4d6165a42a17d1ac6a46f13dc11d4a3d8d4fcd7b16f88f0fecc659bd1a9ddd1cb79002a8b1ab9daf4da549dd2e516806cc4603dd20cbdde175bd5961049'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
  'password' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2008dff1d727007691867904af3a96677ec81847ff943470a9596b184ffdb8b0de03e6fa68d9a6cb03170bff78d8d50f703bcec9120727b9eee5dbceeb1bc26e'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2008dff1d727007691867904af3a96677ec81847ff943470a9596b184ffdb8b0de03e6fa68d9a6cb03170bff78d8d50f703bcec9120727b9eee5dbceeb1bc26e'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
</pre>pre one: 5647f4d6165a42a17d1ac6a46f13dc11d4a3d8d4fcd7b16f88f0fecc659bd1a9ddd1cb79002a8b1ab9daf4da549dd2e516806cc4603dd20cbdde175bd5961049

one
```

Run Three:

```
select user.salt, user.password from user where user.userid=:id1<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b>
  'salt' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'5df34898a394a3476ed96bc16b5b015a776c25912ba5b94427ff09e2331267ad100f7218e636eb50635a459ca5cfa00cee846db889a920c87cb25bddb47888bf'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'5df34898a394a3476ed96bc16b5b015a776c25912ba5b94427ff09e2331267ad100f7218e636eb50635a459ca5cfa00cee846db889a920c87cb25bddb47888bf'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
  'password' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'3f9e5a9a6d387d411439d51744b3bb402c67cba64a36f47d82fe92d583ead1e26752aeeaf42bca12d8ef18a5423d2cab79c985f4fbfce1a6e53532453787419e'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'3f9e5a9a6d387d411439d51744b3bb402c67cba64a36f47d82fe92d583ead1e26752aeeaf42bca12d8ef18a5423d2cab79c985f4fbfce1a6e53532453787419e'</font> <i>(length=128)</i>
</pre>pre one: 5df34898a394a3476ed96bc16b5b015a776c25912ba5b94427ff09e2331267ad100f7218e636eb50635a459ca5cfa00cee846db889a920c87cb25bddb47888bf

one
```

Comment: echo $query; - what is the result? did you try it from the command line or phpmyadmin if you have it.

Comment: Your prefix isn't current right?  aka, you're not using a reserved MYSQL word.  Also, I'm sure you are in the rest of your code, but make sure the PDO object is a singleton.

Comment: Define "random results", dude.

Comment: The db_prefix is defined elsewhere as a constant (in this case, an empty string).  It's designed to let me force databases to co-exist since my webhost limits me to 2.

Comment: You say the problem is your MySQL query, yet you haven't shown us one fully-constructed yet. Please post the actual query that fails.

Comment: very-very odd, "select ".db_prefix."user.salt ..." tuns in to "select user.password, ..."

Comment: Voted to close. It turned to be an exceptionally bad question. "I have a query" but no query. "I have data" but no data. "Random results" - what are these results? Rows? Some values generated by ValueFromPasswordAndSaltFromExtremelyLongAndNoWonderObscure function or what?

Comment: That would be because I've been tinkering with the code, and forgot to revert to the old version when editing that data in.  Even under the original version, though, the query worked fine in PHPMyAdmin, it's only the PHP results that are erroneous.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I've edited in the query.  I'll edit in the random results in a second.

Comment: That is not enough. Post full logs as it's described in my edited answer.

Comment: Please add the actual output given by PHP, otherwise we won't know where the output you've presented us with comes from.

Comment: I've put in the actual output.  It's a bit ugly.

Comment: it is better to watch *html source* in your browser. It has a better look

Comment: "userid=:id1" What is **1** here? is it sticked from some other output?

Comment: The 1 is coming from a check I ran on the userid being input.  (I'm still trying to figure out what's going on my end, and I forgot to segregate the code I'm displaying here from the code I'm experimenting with.  Since I'm out of ideas, that shouldn't be an ongoing problem)  I'll update the source code displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT
Okay, another answer titled "How to ask sane questions".

If you encountered a strange behavior and going to ask a question about it, a **detailed investigation report** is a must.

There is no point in telling us "I did this, I did that". You are going to ask US - thus, supply US with the same data you have.

Post your table structure
Post the table dump
Post three logs from three attempts with full debugging info:
The query
The results that are "random".

**Do copy/paste results at whole**
Var_dump output contains variable length - there is none in your current results.

the word "returned" hinting me that there is something about generateValueFromPasswordAndSalt, an oddly called function....

Comment: When only one result is possible anyway (userid is guaranteed unique), does ORDER BY matter?  Further, how can that cause me to get results that aren't even in the database?

Comment: if it returns random rows, then NOT only one is possible.

Comment: Not random rows, random results.  As in values that don't exist in the DB.

Comment: As far as I can tell.  Unless this one query is grabbing from another DB -- and I don't think any other DB's present on my system would have the right result lengths, anyway -- I am in the correct DB.

Comment: What logs are you asking for?  I'll generate them as soon as I can.

Comment: @Run just what your program prints out. When you run it, it prints the query and the results. Copy|paste the program output in your question. From three dofferent runs you described, with three different field sets